# gcc compile error: passing argument to parameter here

Tags: objective-c, c, gcc

I'm just getting started with c and objective c, and I made this simple script:

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int s;
int main()
{
NSString *s = (@"Hello World");
printf(s);
return 0
}
```

However, when I try to compile it in gcc, I get the error:

> passing argument to parameter here
>
> int      printf(const char * __restrict, ...) __printflike(1, 2);

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry that this will sound rude, but a better question is what aren't you doing wrong -- so much so with this simple snippet that i think you're trolling. If you're for real, I would recommend you pick up a good book to get started with, and http://www.pdf-archive.com/2012/06/08/objective-c-programming/objective-c-programming.pdf is a good (and apparently free) starter for C/ObjC.

Comment: Yeah, I made a few mistakes in general, (I'm really green and it was midnight, I corrected it with what I should've known at the time) but the main problem was that I couldn't get anything I put in/copied to run. As Charlie Burns pointed out below, the main problem I was having is that I didn't know how to link the framework. (couldn't find what turned out to be -framework anywhere) Now that it will compile, I can really start learning! PS thanks for the book, I intend to read it cover to cover! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(void)
{
    NSLog(@"Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

NSLog takes an objective-C string and prints it to the console.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I see now. I made a few stupid mistakes there.              But now I get this error, and it STILL won't compile:                                                   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Are you doing this inside xcode? If not, you need to link with their libraries to get NSLog.

Comment: No, I'm not using Xcode. How would I link with the libraries?

Comment: Try a command line like "gcc file.m -framework Cocoa" where file.m is the name of your file.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That worked and for some reason I couldn't find the -framework command in the man pages or elsewhere. I'm a little new at this, so again, thanks!

Comment: Usually folks learning C and ObjC on the Mac use xcode. Xcode is a big complex GUI, but it's pretty much required for anything nontrivial.